# Regex expression oracle sql 11g to parse XML

Tags: xml, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I've got a column in a table which contains xml type of data but is in a varchar format. An example raw of data is:

```
  <old_template_code>BEVA30D</old_template_code><old_template_name>Beva
 30D France calls capped
 15p</old_template_name><new_template_code>BEVA24M</new_template_code><new_template_name>Beva 24M France Calls Capped 15p</new_template_name>
```

I wonder what regex expression do I have to use to retrieve for example 'BEVA30D' from `<old_template_code>`?

I've tried

```
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(table.column,
            '<old_template_code>*</old_template_code>') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XML` approach is **definitely** the better one always.

Still, A regular expression approach.

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr(table.column,'<old_template_code>.*</old_template_code>'),
                      '(<old_template_code>)(.*)(</old_template_code>)',
                       '\2')
from table;
```

Comment: I accept this answer simply because the xml parser fails after the 150 row probably because some of the xml data is incorrect. However, this approach did not fail.

Comment: I started out of interest to crack this with simple regex. I know the cons as well.

Comment: @user3793865, in your question you are not mentioning anything about possibly garbage'd data in your XML column, nor are you giving us an example of such garbage'd data.

Answer (score 5):

Forget about regexp. Use the native XMLType functionality ...

```
select extractValue(xmlparse(content T.column), '/old_template_code')
from table T;
```

In an example based on your sample XML data:

```
with source$ as (
    select q'{
<old_template_code>BEVA30D</old_template_code><old_template_name>Beva
 30D France calls capped
 15p</old_template_name><new_template_code>BEVA24M</new_template_code><new_template_name>Beva 24M France Calls Capped 15p</new_template_name>
}' as source_xml
    from dual
)
select extractValue(xmlparse(content source_xml), '/old_template_code')
from source$;
```

gives me the value of

```
BEVA30D
```

Enjoy.

PS: Moreover, forget about stackoverflow.com, use [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions261.htm#SQLRF06207). :-)

Comment: but I need to extract the data from a column in a table. That was just an example row. I need to select table.column from table and get the value

Comment: I believe that you **are able** to get an example code snippet and adapt it to your needs. But if not, ... Answer updated.

Comment: Nice!  +1 for the example.  One possible issue though is the varchar field that's supposed to contain valid XML will almost certainly have some non-xml garbage that might cause an XML parser issues.